# Not able to log in as root in fedora 17

Tags: permissions, fedora, root, su

I am not able to log in as root in Fedora 17

Error is

> su: cannot set groups: Operation not permitted

What to do to solve this error The permission has been changed to

```
-rwxrwxrwx
```

I want to change permission to

```
-rwsrwsrws.
```

Comment: The permissions of _what_ have been changed?

Comment: Show the entries for `root` in `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/groups`. What does `ls -l /bin/su` say? If those permissions are screwed up, `rpm -qf /bin/su` tells you it belongs to `coreutils`; `yum reinstall coreutils` (or, less brutally, `rpm --setperms coreutils`) should fix that.